# Why when I convert from zoo to ts do I get a decimal index?

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

Heres the situation, I am pulling a data set from Quandl as a zoo object. Then using the apply. function I am converting it before moving it to a ts object.
When I convert from zoo to ts, I get a decimal valued index. Is there any way to get the index back into a "Y-m-d"?

- Sample code:

  ```
  data <- Quandl("YAHOO/AAPL", trim_start="01-01-2000", trim_end="01-01-2010", type="zoo")
  data <- data[,4]
  data <- apply.weekly(data, mean)
  data <- ts(data, frequency=52, class="ts", 
                   start=c(year(start(data)),week(start(data))))
  ```

  - Then I use:

    ```
       head(index(data))
    ```
  - What I get is:

    ```
       [1] 2000.019 2000.038 2000.058 2000.077 2000.096 2000.115
    ```
  - What I want is:

    ```
       [1] "01-08-2000" "01-15-2000" "01-22-2000" "01-29-2000"
    ```
  - where that last line comes from:

    ```
       format(date_decimal(index(data)), "%m-%d-%Y")
    ```

So I figure I can look at this two ways,

(1) Can I change the index after ts? (e.g. go from the first index to the second - above)  I cannot seem to find any indication that I can

(2) Can I prevent ts from setting the index in decimal form?

Before anyone asks, this is for a project for a TS class that I am in, and I do not want to use the Quandl collapse(?) call - there are a handful of reasons, but the major reason is that I want to minimize the number of calls to Quandl. Thus, I need to pull the data in daily form - which means it must come down in zoo, but I need it to output in ts after I collapse on the user side. - I am writing a shiny app for this course and this index malarky is driving me up a wall.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `zooreg` which is another type offered by the zoo package to aid with `ts` types:

> ```
> ‘zooreg’ is the creator for the S3 class ‘"zooreg"’ for regular
>  ‘"zoo"’ series. It inherits from ‘"zoo"’ and is the analogue to
>  ‘ts’.
> ```

Here is quick try:

```
R> aapl <- Quandl("YAHOO/AAPL", trim_start="01-01-2000", trim_end="01-01-2010", type="zoo")
R> weeklyaapl <- apply.weekly(aapl[,4], mean)
R> summary(as.zooreg(weeklyaapl))
     Index            as.zooreg(weeklyaapl)
 Min.   :2000-01-07   Min.   : 13.3        
 1st Qu.:2002-07-06   1st Qu.: 22.3        
 Median :2005-01-03   Median : 56.0        
 Mean   :2005-01-03   Mean   : 70.6        
 3rd Qu.:2007-07-04   3rd Qu.:104.7        
 Max.   :2009-12-31   Max.   :210.8        
R> head(weeklyaapl)
2000-01-07 2000-01-14 2000-01-21 2000-01-28 2000-02-04 2000-02-11 
   102.588     94.975    108.828    108.063    102.825    112.762 
R>
```

The date index object can still be formatted to your liking.

Comment: I think that trick will work - I was stuck on using the HoltWinters() function form the {stats} package which requires a ts object. I will just pass it to the hw() function from the {forecast} function instead and I believe I can just still leave it as a zoo object taking that route. Thanks!

Comment: That actually will not work, it appears that the forecast package also takes ts objects. So I am back to trying to figure out how to get a ts object with the appropriate format date index...